# SQL query, join on a manipulated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database table with the following column structure and data (1 column example only)

```
[ProductRaw] [nvarchar](255) NULL
One Kind of Product (CatA)
Another Product (CatB)
Yet Another Product (CatC)
```

I cannot change this column due to other requirements but I also need to do a 'join' on a clean version of this column. The clean version would look like this

```
[ProductClean] [nvarchar](255) NULL
One Kind of Product
Another Product
Yet Another Product
```

What would the best way to do this in SQL server be? I know it can be done using  the following

```
DECLARE @Sql varchar(50) = 'One Kind of Product (CatA)'    

SELECT
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(@sql,' (','.'),2)
```

Is there a better way to do this (eg such as calculated column)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `like`:

```
on ProductRaw like ProductClean + '%'
```

However, my recommendation is to alter the table with a computed column:

```
alter table t
    add ProductClean as (left(ProductRaw, charindex(' (', ProductRaw + ' (') - 1)));
```

Then you can add an index on `ProductClean` and do a more sensible join:

```
on t.ProductClean = ?.ProductClean
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to create a separate ***index view*** with all the columns of existing table and an additional column naming *ProductClean*.

```
CREATE VIEW [P_RawWithClean] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

      SELECT *
           , RTRIM(SUBSTRING([ProductRaw], 1, CHARINDEX('(', [ProductRaw] + '(') - 1)) AS [ProductClean]
       FROM [YourTableName]

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_RawWithClean ON P_RawWithClean(ProductClean)
```

Now, you can use this view for any JOIN with *ProductClean* or *ProductRaw*. The index view will give you better performance. Moreover, you can create non clustered index on any columns if needed.